# cURL not working on php server

Tags: php, curl, administrator

I have just developed php app but then I have found out that the php server where i am running  the app is without curl.

Is there any way to get around it? or do I have to contact the administrator?

Thanks fo suggestions!

Comment: Rewrite your script to work without CURL ot contact the administrator and have him install CURL. Those are the options.

Answer (score 1):

you have to contact the admin, if your trying to do basic things you could try to use javascript to get the data you need then thru a post url send it to the php script but your probably better off contacting the admin

Answer (score 1):

If [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/allow_url_fopen) wrappers are enabled you can fetch remote files using functions such as [file](http://php.net/file) or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: if he doesn't have access to CURL i doubt he has access to fopen and file_get_contents, it is probably a free service that wants to block scrapping or something